# Not able to call "loadmoredata" function when scrolled to the bottom in data table lwc salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lazy-loading

I have created a lightning web component in which i am using lightning data table. Now, i am try to implement infinite lazy loading but unable to call my **loadmoredata** function. here is my code component code:

```
<lightning-datatable
    key-field="Id"
    data={searchData}
    show-row-number-column
    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
    onsave ={handleSave}
    draft-values={draftValues}
    columns={columns}
    sorted-by={sortBy}
    sorted-direction={sortDirection}
    onsort={handleSortdata}
    enable-infinite-loading
    is-loading={isLoading}
    onloadmore={loadMoreData}>

</lightning-datatable>
```

Here is my js controller code:

```
loadMoreData(event) {
    //Display a spinner to signal that data is being loaded
    //this.isLoading = true;
    //Display "Loading" when more data is being loaded
      this.loadMoreStatus = 'Loading';
      const currentRecord = this.searchData
      const lastRecId = currentRecord[currentRecord.length - 1].Id;
      Console.log('jdfnddk'+this.loadMoreStatus);
        workItemList()
        .then(result  => {
            const currentData = result.sobList;
            //Appends new data to the end of the table
            const newData = currentRecord.concat(currentData);
            this.data = newData; 
            if (this.data.length >= this.totalNumberOfRows) {
                this.loadMoreStatus = 'No more data to load';
            } else {
                this.loadMoreStatus = '';
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('-------error-------------'+error);
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community, Can I ask that instead of telling us what it is not doing, tell us what it is doing. For instance, are you getting any errors? Do any of your console.log statements show up in the console?

Comment: Please do not edit your post to have a screenshot of the code. The code you posted was mostly fine (if you have any apex that you need to include please include it).

Answer (score 1):

[LWC lightning-datatable Infinite Scrolling Not Working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279776/lwc-lightning-datatable-infinite-scrolling-not-working)

This question was dealing with the same issue. Basically you have to set a height on the datatable in order to use infinite scrolling.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and get back to you !